# Regular expressions on substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to compare the name of a city , with a list of the city by a regular expression . The problem is that if I try "Roma" , get the "Arcinazzo Romano" city (which contains ROMA ) and not the "ROMA" city. You know tell me a regular functioning ?

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried?

Comment: `/^Roma$/i` include the start and end identifiers and case insensitive flag

Answer (score 2):

You could simply check if your specific term was surrounded by white-space or was located at the beginning or ending of your string:

```
(^|\s)Roma($|\s)
```

An example of this in action might look like :

[image]

Or if you just explicitly wanted to check if your string was "Roma" exactly, with no other characters, just use the expression starting / ending characters :

```
^Roma$
```

Answer (score 2):

try using an anchor to guarantee ROMA is the beginning of the line

```
/^ROMA/
```

http://regexone.com/lesson/line_beginning_end

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ you edited the meaning of the answer. Leave that up to the poster please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for the city whose name **is** "Roma" but not the cities whose name *contains* "Roma", use delimiters to check whether the specified string starts *and* ends with "Roma", using the `^` (start of string) delimiter and the `$` (end of string) delimiter, as follows:

```
^Roma$
```